# Run a pydev module from python or ipython or command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev, ipython

I have a project in Pydev.

It contains a number of modules.

I would like to run some of the modules from the command line.

However, if I try to run a module e.g.

```
%run snapshot_scripy.py
```

I get missing module errors

```
ImportError: No module named 'sys_fns'
```

So I assume the problem is that I am missing pythonpath.

What is the correct way to set pythonpath using the pythonpath from my pydev project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options:

1) set `$PYTHONPATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`. This will affect both python and ipython.

2) make ipython change the path on startup. edit your ipython startup script, very likely something like `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00run.ipy`, and add

```
import sys
path = 'path/to/project'
if not path in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, path)
del path
```

if you are working in ipython a lot in that project, you may add `%cd 'path/to/project'` to the startup file as well.